# Speed of air required to support a hovering helicopter

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum

The question is

> "A toy helicopter has mass m = 0.30 kg and blade rotors of radius R = 0.25 m. It may be assumed that as the blades turn, the air exactly under the blades is pushed downwards with speed v. The density of air is ρ = 1.2 kg m^−3. Determine the speed v when the helicopter just hovers".

The answer is found by calculating the rate of change of momentum of the air which is equivalent to the upwards force on the helicopter. Thus it can be equated to the weight of the helicopter to find v.

My question is, doesn't the rate of change of momentum give the net force? So in this case the rate of change of the momentum of the air would be equal to both the weight of the air and the downwards force of the helicopter on the air. Consequently, wouldn't it be incorrect to equate this to the upwards force acting on the helicopter? Instead I think you would subtract the weight of the air from this rate of change of momentum which is now equivalent to the upwards force acting on the helicopter and so can be equated to the helicopter's weight. Could someone please let me know if this is correct or if I have misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

So when the helicopter blades are rotating - they are pushing what could be considered stationary parcels of air downwards(for simplicity) - imparting momentum on that parcel of air. By conservation of momentum, the momentum imparted on the air is equal but opposite in direction to the momentum imparted on the hellicopter. So we can find the amount of momentum per second the hellicopter is imparting:

In 1 second it pushes a mass : $\rho(A  v)$ down ($A$ being the area of the circle that the blades trace out.), thus it imparts a force equal to $\rho Avg$, by Newton's laws, for the hellicopter to hover the weight force of the hellicopter must be balanced by this rotary force. To accelerate upwards it would need to push the air even faster downwards.

Comment: Since there is a net external force acting on the system (gravity) wouldn't the value calculated for the momentum imparted on the air also include the effect of gravity? Consequently, since the rate of change of momentum gives the net force, then wouldn't it be wrong to equate the change in momentum of the air with that of the helicopter (since they have different mass and thus weights)?

Comment: Well lets use your logic - why don't we find all of the air on the ground? We treat the atmosphere as an incompressible fluid.

Comment: We are also looking at the *change* in momentum, not the total momentum.

Comment: What does it mean in this context to treat the atmosphere as an incompressible fluid? Does this mean we don't need to consider the force of gravity acting on the air?